# Binding a view model to a ComboBox

Tags: xaml, data-binding, combobox, uwp

I am making a UWP app and I have bound an `ObservableCollection<EduRole>` to a `ComboBox`. I can see the items populated in the `ComboBox`. But I also need to set it's `SelectedItem` property which I cant get to work.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="EducationalLevelComboBoxUpdate"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind EduRoleList, Mode=OneWay}"

    <!--IS THIS OKAY?-->
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind Path=User.EduRole.Read, Mode=OneWay}"

    PlaceholderText="Select educational role">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:EduRoleViewModel">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Read}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Source:

```
  private ObservableCollection<EduRoleViewModel> EduRoleList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<EduRoleViewModel>();
```

ViewModel:

```
public class EduRoleViewModel
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Read { get; set; }
}
```

User is object of a class called UserViewModel that has `EduRoleViewModel` type property here's that class:

```
class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private EduRoleViewModel _eduRole;
    public EduRoleViewModel EduRole
    {
        get { return _eduRole; }
        set
        {
            _eduRole = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {            
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I want the `Read` property of the `EduRole` property of `UserViewModel` to be the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox`

Comment: Is `EduRoleList` a property of a class? Which one? Whatever class `EduRoleList` belongs to, we'll call that `SecretViewModelX`. If the binding works and populates the ComboBox, `SecretViewModelX` is the DataContext for your ComboBox. Your `SelectedItem` binding assumes that `SecretViewModelX` has a property named `User`, whcih has a property named `EduRole`, which has a property named `Read`: `SelectedItem="{x:Bind Path=User.EduRole.Read, Mode=OneWay}"`. So `User` should be `UserViewModel`. Why you put `Mode=OneWay` on it, I can't imagine. Do you know what it means?

Comment: @Ed The default mode of `x:Bind` is `OneTime`.

Comment: @Clemens Ah, thanks.

Comment: When the ItemsSource is bound to a collection of EduRoleViewModel, the SelectedItem should also be a EduRoleViewModel. So the binding should probably be `{x:Bind Path=User.EduRole}`. You may also have to make sure that the selected item is actually a member of the source collection (depending on how equality comparison is implemented).